# Cart still showing the product which has been deleted Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this function which allows user to add product to cart but if the product is deleted in admin panel it still shows in the cart, any idea on how to remove the product in cart which has been deleted in admin dashboard?

So I tried this to check if the id exists or not and I got an error `Call to a member function isEmpty() on integer`

Checkout Controller

```
   public function store(Request $request)
 {
    foreach(session('cart')  as $productId =>$item);
    $product = product::find($productId);
    if(!$productId->isEmpty())
    //Insert into orders table
    $order = Order::create([
        'shipping_email' => $request->email,
        'shipping_name' => $request->name,
        'shipping_city' => $request->city,
         'user_id'=> auth()->user()->id,

    ]);

    //Insert into order product table
    if ($order) {
        $total = 0;
        foreach(session('cart')  as $productId =>$item) {
           if (empty($item)) {
               continue;
           }
           $product = product::find($productId);
           OrderProduct::create([
            'order_id' => $order->id ?? null,
            'product_id' => $productId,
           // $products=DB::table('products')->where('id',$id)->get();
            'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
            'Subtotal' =>$item['price'] * $item['quantity'],
            'total' => $total += $item['price'] * $item['quantity'],
            'price' => $product->price,
            'name' => $product->name,
            'info' => $product->info,
        ]);
```

Comment: Removing/modifying a Product that is in someone's session will not update it unless you make a call to the database to check if said product exists/is still the same. Sessions are designed to be snapshots of data and are not intrinsically aware of changes.

Comment: How do I make that call, to the database? @TimLewis

Comment: It's not so much a question of how, but a question of when; if the product was deleted, it probably won't show up on the storefront (wherever you're displaying products), so there won't be an easy time to cross-reference. Generally, you handle this at checkout; right before saving an order, check the products, list prices, inform the user if the product is still available, etc.

Comment: Nice I get your point, I tried something before and I got an errors can I update the question with checkout controller? @TimLewis

Comment: For sure! It might be a little broad of a concept for an answer on Stackoverflow, but if you can show your attempt, and any errors you're getting, that would be a good step forward.

Comment: okay one moment, @Tim Lewis

Comment: I have updated the question @TimLewis

Comment: There we go; you're almost doing the correct thing. `$product = product::find($productId);` this will return `null` if the product has been removed from the database; you just need to handle the check and follow-up better. `if(!$productId->isEmpty())` isn't quite right, as `$productId` is simply an `int`. You can simply do `if(!$product){ ... // Remove from cart, inform user, etc. }`

Comment: If there is only one product in cart which has been deleted it returns what I want(product isn't available) but if there is two products one has been deleted and another is not deleted I get an error Trying to get property of non-object, I guess it checks and returns error in general  @Tim Lewis

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to modify your check to handle this for all products in your cart. You've got a loop, but you continue to insert into even if the check fails.

Comment: Can you explain a little more please I'm little bit confused  @Tim Lewis

Comment: This was what I meant by it might be too broad. You're looping over the product ids and checking if the product still exists in the database, but if that check fails for one, but not another, you're still trying to create the `Order` and `OrderProduct` entries as if everything still exists. You need to remove the product from the cart, redirect away from saving an inform your user. You should only continue to saving if no products fail the check.

Answer (score 0):

You delete product from the admin panel but don't update session which have still this product in array. Try maybe get in session only id's of products and in controller get data from db with this id's and next pass to view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the values stored in your session after every delete operation. In laravel (according to their official documentation) you can do this as follow.

```
    $request->session()->forget('removed_product_id',$id);
```

Or if you want to use session facade

```
    Session::forget('removed_product_id',$id);
```

Call this statement after every delete operation. You can call them in delete controller function.

Comment: Where do I put that `Session::forget('removed_product_id');` is it in product controller delete method or in checkout controller like in the question @Hussain Abdullah

Comment: Yes in product controller delete method. And replace 'removed_product_id' with the name you used while creating session. And also assign $id with the id of deleted product.

Comment: This will not work. `session()->forget()` only affects the current session. If I, as an admin, delete a Product, `session()->forget()` will not affect the session of any other users. My session will update, but only my session.

Comment: @TimLewis  you are right. It will only work for the admin session only. I forgot about other users.

Comment: I might check if one of the product doesn't exist it should return  back to cart  saying one of the products has been deleted but user would not know which product so how can I delete the product when redirected back to cart or any other idea @Tim Lewis